# Should systemctl stop honour Restart=always?

Tags: systemd

Is/should "Restart=always" be honoured when "systemctl stop docker.service" is excuted?

My understanding (which is limited) is that systemctl stop should stop with an Exit Code of 0. I then expect the docker.service to retstart as "Restart=always"  is configured i.e should restart it no matter what the exit code is, but this does not seem to happen.

Is systemctl stop a special case and if so how do I test "Restart=always" is working by getting dockerd to exit with a status code of 0?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comments greatly appreciated. Fiddling around with the above (best description of it based on my lack of knowledge) this is what I believe the behaviour is:

- The Eval/gdp script above seems to work on docker.service. It causes the dockerd process to exit and it is restarted. There is no message written to /var/log/messages to say the the processes exited with status Zero. If I change the scirpt to use exit status 1 this is written to messages log file as status=1 and the service is also restarted
- SIGTERM also causes docker.service to stop, no exit code status to be written to /var/log/messages and the process to be restarted
- systemctl stop docker.service causes the process to stop and it is not restarted
- systemctl stop systemd-udevd causes the process to stop and it is not restarted i.e. its like a SIGSTOP

The last point would seem to suggest that  the STOP command does not honour restart=always by design.

Answer (score 0):

No. Yes. And I'm not sure.

For a program which is linked against libc, like udev:

```
eval $(systemctl show -p MainPID systemd-udevd)
gdb -p $MainPID
p (void)_exit(0)
quit
```

However Docker is written in `go`, which is unusually unfriendly to calling C functions (and maybe uses it's own syscall implementations?).  So I do not know if this would work on dockerd.

If you just want to double-check that `Restart=always` works how you think it does, systemd-udevd.service already uses `Restart=always`.  So you can demonstrate `Restart=always` using the above.  It worked for me :-).

Comment: The usual way of checking automatic restarts, at least from long practice in the daemontools world, is to send the service a `TERM` signal with `svc -t` or similar.

Comment: @JdeBP ah, that's a really good point that I did not address.  I think I was imagining the process would *not* exit with 0 in that case.  I suppose it can depend whether the process has any need to handle `SIGTERM` explicitly.  If not, it might not register any signal handler, and then you would see an abnormal exit (`WIFSIGNALED`).

Comment: … which does not affect `always` restarts.

Comment: @JdeBP 'how do I test "Restart=always" is working by getting dockerd to exit with a status code of 0'.